# What is the 'start' event in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I noticed in Bostock's [most recent block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/70d5541b547cc222aa02) he has a 'start' event:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(d3.range(n))
  .enter().append("div")
  .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i + Math.random() * n / 4; })
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .on("start", function repeat() {
        d3.active(this)
            .styleTween("background-color", function() { return whiteblue; })
          .transition()
            .delay(1000)
            .styleTween("background-color", function() { return blueorange; })
          .transition()
            .delay(1000)
            .styleTween("background-color", function() { return orangewhite; })
          .transition()
            .delay(n)
            .on("start", repeat);
      });
```

Does anyone know what this does?

Is it the equivalent to on load or is it fired after the delay period when the transition begins?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That block is written in `d3` v4.  It looks like the v3 [transition.each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) has been renamed [transition.on](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on) (which makes more sense).  That said `start` has always been an event-type for a transition:

> If type is specified, adds a listener for transition events,
>   supporting "start", "end" and "interrupt" events. The listener will be
>   invoked for each individual element in the transition.
>
> **The start event is invoked during the first asynchronous callback
>   (tick) of the transition**, before any tweens are invoked. For
>   transitions with zero delay, this is typically about 17ms after the
>   transition is scheduled. State events are useful for triggering
>   instantaneous changes to each element, such as changing attributes
>   that cannot be interpolated.

To answer you specific question (my bolding above) "or is it for when the transition begins after the delay period" - yes.

Answer (score 4):

I've been poking around trying to figure this out.  "start" is not a normal DOM event and is not one of the events supplied by D3.  After doing some research, here's what I've come to find out:

"Transitions are a limited form of key frame animation with only two key frames: *start* and *end*"

"The start event is then dispatched, and the transition initializes its tweens, which may involve retrieving starting values from the DOM and constructing interpolators."

From: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/

(that's linked to directly from the d3-transition repo @ https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#active see "working with transitions" link).

I believe that the D3-transition library being used in the example implicitly uses the same - that is, the transitions have two key frames.  The "start" "event" actually represents the first key frame.  In fact, there's a slight delay when the transition begins so it makes sense that one would wait until the keyframe "started".